# How to export all words from sql table or sql database

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, database, t-sql

Let's say we have following table.

```
UserId | Message
-------|-------------
1      | Hi, have a nice day
2      | Hi, I had a nice day
```

I need to have all { Hi,-have-a-nice-day-I-had } words separately.
Is there any way to do that ? What if I want to export words from whole database tables ?

Similar results would be also good.

Comment: What is your end goal with this? Are you trying to do fulltext search? Also which server platform are you targeting exactly? You use two in your tags.

Comment: Are you really using both Microsoft SQL Server and MySQL? If not, please remove the irrelevant tag(s).

Comment: @Damien  I need the solution in all followed tags. Thank you for your comment.

Comment: @Pekka My end goal is to do fill out a Auto-Complete box

Comment: @manurajhada maybe as a sql query, view. but anyway I just need to export those and after that I can convert results.

Comment: I can give you solution for SQL server if that's acceptable. It uses xml conversion internally and don't know how to do that on MySQL.

Comment: I want you to draw the result here, and let us know wat you have tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:In Sql server 2005 or above

```
create table yourtable(RowID int, Layout varchar(200))
INSERT yourtable VALUES (1,'hello,world,welcome,to,tsql')
INSERT yourtable VALUES (2,'welcome,to,stackoverflow')


;WITH SplitSting AS
(
    SELECT
        RowID,LEFT(Layout,CHARINDEX(',',Layout)-1) AS Part
            ,RIGHT(Layout,LEN(Layout)-CHARINDEX(',',Layout)) AS Remainder
        FROM YourTable
        WHERE Layout IS NOT NULL AND CHARINDEX(',',Layout)>0
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        RowID,LEFT(Remainder,CHARINDEX(',',Remainder)-1)
            ,RIGHT(Remainder,LEN(Remainder)-CHARINDEX(',',Remainder))
        FROM SplitSting
        WHERE Remainder IS NOT NULL AND CHARINDEX(',',Remainder)>0
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        RowID,Remainder,null
        FROM SplitSting
        WHERE Remainder IS NOT NULL AND CHARINDEX(',',Remainder)=0
)
SELECT part FROM SplitSting ORDER BY RowID
```

[**SQLFIDDLE DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/fade8/2)

Comment: To complete AnandPhadke solution to fit with asked question you need to change last line to following line.  SELECT DISTINCT part FROM SplitSting

Comment: Yes for sitinct values you should do that

Answer (score 2):

Well, ok, here it goes.

In SQL Server you can use this...

```
SELECT word = d.value('.', 'nvarchar(max)')
FROM
    (SELECT xmlWords = CAST(
        '<a><i>' + replace([Message], ' ', '</i><i>') + '</i></a>' AS xml) 
        FROM MyMessageTbl) T(c)
    CROSS APPLY c.nodes('/a/i') U(d)
```

And I hope that for MySQL you can use the same thing, using XML support - ExtractValue() etc.

EDIT: explanation

```
 - replace([Message], ' ', '</i><i>') replaces e.g. 'my word' with 'my</i><i>word'
 - then I add the beginning and the end of xml -> '<a><i>my</i><i>word</i></a>', so I have a valid xml... and cast it to xml type to be able to do something with it
 - I select from that xml and shred xml nodes '/a/i' it to rows using CROSS APPLY c.nodes('/a/i'); 
   alias rows using U(d), so one 'i' maps to column d (e.g. 'my')
 - d.value('.', 'nvarchar(max)') extracts node content and casts it to character type
```

Comment: If AnandPhadke haven't answered I would use your solution. Thank you

Comment: No problem. Just pay attention that if you have to refine your resultset (split around additional characters, remove characters etc) it's easier with xml. So my solution is in that case better :) sorry AnandPhadke.

Comment: The question is split on comma

Comment: No, it isn't. However, if you want to split it around comma characters, use *replace([Message], ',', '</i><i>')* where appropriate.